# Angular LazyLoad module calling strange component

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular7, ng-modules

With lazy loading enabled in my Angular 7 app when I route to a child component I'm getting errors about `MainComponent` not being in any module.

In `app.module.ts` the `MainComponent` is the one that loads when the app starts up.  I'm seeing that component without issues.  I then added this to my `app.routing.ts`

```js
{ path: 'ftb', loadChildren: './floor-to-book/floor-to-book.module#FloorToBookModule'},
```

and in `floor-to-book-routing.module.ts I've got this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: ':id', component: FloorToBookSweepComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FloorToBookRoutingModule {
}
```

If I go to `.../ftb/1234` then I get this error:

> Error: Component MainComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
>   Error: Component MainComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

I've verified that `MainComponent` only exists in the `app-routing.module.ts` and `app.module.ts`

Comment: can you provide stackblitz link also? it will be helpful for quick answers.

Comment: No, because this is part of a huge project.  I know lazy loading of children works fine, I use it in multiple projects.  So I don't know how to reproduce this in a stackblitz.

Comment: Can you provide `app.module.ts` parts about `MainComponent`? Is it in the `declarations` section?

Comment: Does `FloorToBookSweepComponent` use `MainComponent`?